# .Net App Stuck in Dev Mode but Config for Release

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a project built in .Net Core. I'm deploying it to an Ubuntu server running nginx. When I run it locally, everything works. I compile it using the following command:

`dotnet publish --configuration Release --output ~/MyOutFolder`

When I push it to the server, I get the message that:

> The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.

My launchSettings.json shows:

```
   {
     "iisSettings": {
       "windowsAuthentication": false,
       "anonymousAuthentication": true
     },
     "profiles": {
       "WebApp1": {
         "commandName": "Project",
         "launchBrowser": true,
         "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:20498",
         "environmentVariables": {
           "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
         }
       },
       "WebApp2": {
         "commandName": "Project",
         "launchBrowser": true,
         "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:24446",
         "environmentVariables": {
           "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

I have even tried deploying the launchSettings to the server to see if it made a difference. So far, no change.

Are there other settings or factors that might be keeping this locked into Developement mode?
Suggestions for how to resolve this?

Comment: Here's a similar issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986588/the-development-environment-shouldnt-be-enabled-for-deployed-applications

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Thanks for pointing that one out. I looked at it. My web.config doesn't have a config for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT. I tried adding it with a value of Production, and still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Keypoint**

1. The `web.config` file only used for IIS, so we don't need this file in ubuntu server.
2. The `launchSettings.json` file only used for Visual Studio 2022 (IDE), when you deploy it, it will not read the params from this file.

**Solution**

You need to modify the kestrel service definition file and add

```
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```

Then you can fix the issue.

**Tutorials**

[1. [Blog] Deploying a .NET Core 2.0 Web Application to a Production Environment on Ubuntu 16.04 using Nginx](https://medium.com/@JohGeoCoder/deploying-a-net-core-2-0-web-application-to-a-production-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-nginx-683b7e831e6)

[2. [Official Doc] Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=linux-ubuntu&view=aspnetcore-7.0)